# How to connect a BLE device using an app and how to control the device temperature using the app?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to develop an android application to communicate with BLE device.I am not familiar with BLE in android. Using my app it is possible to scan the BLE devices and is visible in list view. But I have no idea how to connect it. I don't want to see the available services or characteristics. Only want to connect the  BLE device using a button in list view.
I have another query how to control the temperature of the BLE device. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Have you tried https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#connectGatt(android.content.Context,%20boolean,%20android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCallback,%20int)? You need to narrow down your question to which step you have problems with so we can answer correctly. For now it's not clear if you have issues building the UI or the code for Bluetooth

Comment: I want to know the code.. how to connect the ble device using button click

Comment: Stack overflow is not a code writing service. You are supposed to first on your own find tutorials, examples, documentation and so on so you can do the work yourself. If you get stuck on a particular issue, feel free to ask a question about the specific issue. Generally, questions here should include some piece of code (not more than what's needed to reproduce the problem). This way, it's more likely someone will answer your question. You can also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Anyway, did you try the connectGatt method I mentioned earlier?